# How do i solve this Postgis error when creating a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

Anyone shed some light on why i am getting this error in postgis, first time user.

Trying to create a table of the warehouse and just threw some random characters in there.

Full error code is:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Warehouse_id" LINE 3: Warehouse_id
> VARCHAR(100),
> ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 58

This is my data:

```
CREATE TABLE Warehouse (
Warehouse_location  VARCHAR(25)
Warehouse_id  VARCHAR(100),
Warehouse_managers  VARCHAR(25)
Warehouse_address  VARCHAR(25)
Warehouse_capacity  VARCHAR(50),
Warehouse_occupied  VARCHAR(50),
Warehouse_loading bays VARCHAR(50),
Warehouse_accesspoints VARCHAR(50),
);
INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Vic','1235','John', '12 Sidney St','500','230','10','5');
INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Vic','1236','Drake', '156 Can Rd','400','250','10','6');
INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Nsw','1237','Dave', '120 Toast Ave','400','240','9','5');
INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Vic','1238','Daniel', '99 Foot St','550','255','10','5');
INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Nsw','1434','Chirs', '21 Jump St','500','270','9','6');
INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Nsw','1734','Liam', '1 Bishop St','500','150','6','5');
INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Vic','7234','Steve', '12 Bewick Grove ','440','250','3','5');
INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Vic','8234','Bob', '23 Rannoch Wood Rd','440','250','11','5');
INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Vic','1224','Kim', '390 Park Ave','550','250','9','6');
INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('SA','4234','Alex', '2 Grange Dr','550','250','10','5');
INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('SA','1734','Ryan', '12 Food St','500','350','10','5');
```

Comment: You Missing a comma?

Comment: Indeed. Just missing a comma at the end of line 2, between `VARCHAR(25)` and `Warehouse_id`

Comment: OK thanks knew something simple missed

Comment: Now just spitting ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 10: );
         ^ on the bracket ?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing several commas and there is a column name with a space. Either wrap it with double quotes `"` or get rid of it, e.g. using `_` (imho much more elegant):

```
CREATE TABLE Warehouse 
( Warehouse_location VARCHAR(25), 
  Warehouse_id VARCHAR(100), 
  Warehouse_managers VARCHAR(25), 
  Warehouse_address VARCHAR(25),
  Warehouse_capacity VARCHAR(50), 
  Warehouse_occupied VARCHAR(50), 
  "Warehouse_loading bays" VARCHAR(50), -- consider using Warehouse_loading_bays instead
  Warehouse_accesspoints VARCHAR(50)
); 

 INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Vic','1235','John', '12 Sidney St','500','230','10','5'); 
 INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Vic','1236','Drake', '156 Can Rd','400','250','10','6'); 
 INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Nsw','1237','Dave', '120 Toast Ave','400','240','9','5'); 
 INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Vic','1238','Daniel', '99 Foot St','550','255','10','5'); 
 INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Nsw','1434','Chirs', '21 Jump St','500','270','9','6'); 
 INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Nsw','1734','Liam', '1 Bishop St','500','150','6','5'); 
 INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Vic','7234','Steve', '12 Bewick Grove ','440','250','3','5'); 
 INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Vic','8234','Bob', '23 Rannoch Wood Rd','440','250','11','5'); 
 INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('Vic','1224','Kim', '390 Park Ave','550','250','9','6'); 
 INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('SA','4234','Alex', '2 Grange Dr','550','250','10','5'); 
 INSERT INTO Warehouse Values('SA','1734','Ryan', '12 Food St','500','350','10','5');
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=705b0fee0d843d3566ef12d72eaa4dd1)